# How to retrieve a value given a key in a json object?

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-mongodb/). I've got this instruction:

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array("author" => "shreef"));
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
   print_r($document)
}
```

Using **print_r** is displaying the structure of the object being returned.

```
Array
(
   [title] => cat with a hat
   [content] => once upon a time a cat with a hat ...
   [_id] => MongoId Object
           (
              [$id] => 4ea2213af7ede43c53000000
           )
)
```

What if I want to grab just the value of the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array("author" => "shreef"));
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
   echo $document['title'];
}
```